# Type mismatch: expected String, actual Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am making some transformation with my DataFrame using Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.

The problem occurs with this line of code `Math.abs($"right.product_price".asInstanceOf[Double] - $"left.product_price".asInstanceOf[Double])`. I want to calculate the absolute difference between `left.product_price` and `right.product_price`. If any of these columns contains `null`, then `null`is converted to `0`.

However, I get an error: "Type mismatch: expected String, actual Column".
How can I do this calculation in a correct way?

```
val result = df.as("left")
    // self-join by gender:
    .join(df.as("right"), ($"left.gender" === $"right.gender")
    // limit to 10 results per record:
    .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"left.product_PK").orderBy($"right.product_PK")))
    .filter($"rn <= 10").drop($"rn")
    // group and collect_list to create products column:
    .groupBy($"left.product_PK" as "product_PK")
    .agg(collect_list(struct($"right.product_PK", Math.abs($"right.product_price".asInstanceOf[Double] - $"right.product_price".asInstanceOf[Double]))) as "products")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Math.abs` and you cannot use `asinstanceOf`. Use SQL `functions.abs` and `cast`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs

...
  .agg(collect_list(struct(
     $"right.product_PK",
    abs($"right.product_price".cast("double)" - $"right.product_price".cast("double"))
  )) as "products")
```

To convert `null` to `0` add `coalesce`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lit}

coalesce(column, lit(0))
```

Comment: Is it the same as this?: `.withColumn("absolute_price_diff", abs(coalesce($"right.product_price", lit(0)) - coalesce($"left.product_price", lit(0))))
        .filter($"rn <= 10").drop($"rn")
        .groupBy($"left.product_PK" as "product_PK")
        .agg(collect_list(struct($"right.product_PK", $"absolute_price_diff")) as "products")`